# Re send mail after 48 hours vtiger

Tags: vtiger

I have the next thing to do in vtiger 5.4

Firstly I assign tickets to users with the status 'Open' inmediatly an email is send to the mail of that user, is the responsability of the user to resolve the ticket, but if the status of the ticket after 48 hours is still 'Open' then i want to re send the mail again to the assigned user.

I have read that this can be done with workflows but I dont have a clear idea of what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
set the workflow as follow:

Step1
[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[image]